# Nautilus opens the home directory only, then proceeds to hang, and make the zsh terminal unresponsive to commands

Tags: nautilus, samba, zsh

I've been having this issue with nautilus, where when i open the terminal and I'm on the home directory, and i run nautilus. I noticed that no matter what directory i was in, it always opened the home directory and then proceeds to make the zsh terminal unresponsive as it still was running. The next time, i run it by force stopping it through `cntrl + c`, it doesn't open any window, and just does nothing in the terminal, just makes the terminal unresponsive to commands. This resets everytime, i reopen the terminal apparently.

I've tried multiple things but to no avail, they didn't fix the issue. Which include:

1. running the batch commands: `sudo apt-get [remove nautilus, autoremove, clean, update, upgrade, install nautilus]`
2. reset the tracker by: `tracker reset -e` and uninstalling and reinstalling it as well along with nautilus.
3. running bleachbit, to clear redundant files and clean the os a bit.
4. Before this issue occured, I had a problem with `net`, but i fixed that by installing samba, and the samba-common-bin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty weird, but I opened my ubuntu the day after, and it is working fine, with no errors whatsoever. Honestly I have no idea why that fixed it, might have to do with the previous things that I did in the question, and that it needed a restart to take into effect.

Tldr; issue has been resolved following a restart.